# How to grant a container privilege to run in a normal user's session in dockerfile

Tags: docker, firefox, debian, debian-stretch

Once building a docker image then use its images like
`docker run -ti firefox-test:latest bash`  then i go to `/usr/bin/` to open firefox :

`root@...:cd /usr/bin`

`root@:/usr/bin/firefox`

then it prompted me with this message:

```
Running Firefox as root in a regular user's session is not supported.  ($HOME is /home/jenkins which is owned by jenkins.)
```

so, looks like running it within root authentication is not supported so i decided to put the `--user <uid>:<gid>` param to the docker command to run it then it can be launched with the given user uid&gid provided. without that params, it went to the `root` session and the message above would display.

So i wonder if there's any that i can do with building Dockerfile so that Firefox can be launched with either root or given user uid&gid  so that i don't need to parse the param `--user <uid>:<gid>` to my docker run command?

```
FROM debian:stretch

#==========
# Ruby 2.5.1
#==========
# cf. Dockerfile for ruby:2.3
#   https://github.com/docker-library/ruby/blob/master/2.3/Dockerfile

# Install Ruby Dependencies
# cf. https://gorails.com/setup/ubuntu/16.04
RUN apt-get update \
    && rubyBuildDeps=' \
        build-essential \
        curl \
        git-core \
        libcurl4-openssl-dev \
        libffi-dev \
        libreadline-dev \
        libsqlite3-dev \
        libssl-dev \
        libxml2-dev \
        libxslt1-dev \
        libyaml-dev \
        software-properties-common \
        sqlite3 \
        wget \
        zlib1g-dev \
    ' \
    && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends $rubyBuildDeps \
    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

# skip installing gem documentation
RUN mkdir -p /usr/local/etc \
    && { \
        echo 'install: --no-document'; \
        echo 'update: --no-document'; \
    } >> /usr/local/etc/gemrc

ENV RUBY_MAJOR 2.5
ENV RUBY_VERSION 2.5.1
ENV RUBY_DOWNLOAD_SHA256 dac81822325b79c3ba9532b048c2123357d3310b2b40024202f360251d9829b1
ENV RUBYGEMS_VERSION 2.7.7

# some of ruby's build scripts are written in ruby
#   we purge system ruby later to make sure our final image uses what we just built
RUN set -ex \
    \
    && buildDeps=' \
        bison \
        libgdbm-dev \
        ruby \
    ' \
    && apt-get update \
    && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends $buildDeps \
    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* \
    \
    && wget -O ruby.tar.gz "https://cache.ruby-lang.org/pub/ruby/${RUBY_MAJOR%-rc}/ruby-$RUBY_VERSION.tar.gz" \
    && echo "$RUBY_DOWNLOAD_SHA256 *ruby.tar.gz" | sha256sum -c - \
    \
    && mkdir -p /usr/src/ruby \
    && tar -xzf ruby.tar.gz -C /usr/src/ruby --strip-components=1 \
    && rm ruby.tar.gz \
    \
    && cd /usr/src/ruby \
    \
# hack in "ENABLE_PATH_CHECK" disabling to suppress:
#   warning: Insecure world writable dir
    && { \
        echo '#define ENABLE_PATH_CHECK 0'; \
        echo; \
        cat file.c; \
    } > file.c.new \
    && mv file.c.new file.c \
    \
    && ./configure --disable-install-doc \
    && make -j"$(nproc)" \
    && make install \
    \
    && apt-get purge -y --auto-remove $buildDeps \
    && cd / \
    && rm -r /usr/src/ruby \
    \
    && gem update --system "$RUBYGEMS_VERSION"

ENV BUNDLER_VERSION 2.0.1

RUN gem install bundler --version "$BUNDLER_VERSION" --force

# install things globally, for great justice
# and don't create ".bundle" in all our apps
ENV GEM_HOME /usr/local/bundle
ENV BUNDLE_PATH="$GEM_HOME" \
    BUNDLE_BIN="$GEM_HOME/bin" \
    BUNDLE_SILENCE_ROOT_WARNING=1 \
    BUNDLE_APP_CONFIG="$GEM_HOME"
ENV PATH $GEM_HOME/bin:$BUNDLE_PATH/gems/bin:$PATH
RUN mkdir -p "$GEM_HOME" "$BUNDLE_BIN" \
    && chmod 777 "$GEM_HOME" "$BUNDLE_BIN"

#===============
# Gecko Driver
#===============

ENV GECKODRIVER_VERSION 0.24.0
RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends unzip && \
    apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends \
      bzip2 \
      libgconf-2-4 \
      libglib2.0-dev \
      libnss3-dev \
      libxi6 \
      xvfb \
    && \
    rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* \
            /var/cache/apt/* && \
    wget https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases/download/v$GECKODRIVER_VERSION/geckodriver-v$GECKODRIVER_VERSION-linux64.tar.gz && \
    tar -zxvf geckodriver-v$GECKODRIVER_VERSION-linux64.tar.gz && \
    mv geckodriver /usr/local/bin/ && \
    chmod +x /usr/local/bin/geckodriver && \
    rm geckodriver-v$GECKODRIVER_VERSION-linux64.tar.gz && \
    apt-get purge -y --auto-remove bzip2

#==========
# Firefox
#==========

ENV FF_LANG="en-US" \
    FF_BASE_URL="https://archive.mozilla.org/pub" \
    FF_PLATFORM="linux-x86_64" \
    FF_INNER_PATH="firefox/releases" \
    FF_VERSION="67.0"

ENV FF_COMP="firefox-${FF_VERSION}.tar.bz2"
ENV FF_URL="${FF_BASE_URL}/${FF_INNER_PATH}/${FF_VERSION}/${FF_PLATFORM}/${FF_LANG}/${FF_COMP}"

RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends unzip && \
    apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends \
      bzip2 \
    && \
    rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* /var/cache/apt/* && \
    wget "${FF_URL}" \
      -O /tmp/firefox-linux.tar.bz2 && \
    tar -xvf /tmp/firefox-linux.tar.bz2 -C /opt && \

    ln -s /opt/firefox/firefox /usr/bin/firefox && \
    chmod +x /usr/bin/firefox && \
    rm /tmp/firefox-linux.tar.bz2 && \
    apt-get purge -y --auto-remove bzip2


#---------------------------
# Dependencies for headless
#---------------------------

RUN apt-get update && \
    headlessDeps=' \
      imagemagick \
      xvfb \
    ' && \
    apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends $headlessDeps && \
    rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* /var/cache/apt/*

#========================
# Font for Chinese
#========================

RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends fonts-arphic-ukai fonts-arphic-uming && \
    rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* /var/cache/apt/*

#==============================================
# On advice from:
#  https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/docker-selenium/issues/87
ENV DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS /dev/null


#==============================================
# Jenkins Agent
#==============================================
# For the Amazon EC2 Container Service Plugin,
# we need the Docker image with an entryPoint which behaves as a
# Jenkins Agent.

# Instal OpenJDK-11
#   cf. https://xmoexdev.com/wordpress/installing-openjdk-9-debian-stretch/

RUN echo deb http://http.debian.net/debian stretch-backports main >> /etc/apt/sources.list.d/stretch-backports.list && \
    apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends -t stretch-backports openjdk-8-jdk && \
    rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* /var/cache/apt/*

# Adapted from Docker Image: jenkins/slave
#   https://hub.docker.com/r/jenkins/slave/~/dockerfile/

ARG user=jenkins
ARG group=jenkins
ARG uid=10000
ARG gid=10000

ENV HOME /home/${user}
RUN groupadd -g ${gid} ${group}
RUN useradd -c "Jenkins user" -d $HOME -u ${uid} -g ${gid} -m ${user}

ARG JENKINS_REMOTING_VERSION=3.20
ARG AGENT_WORKDIR=/home/${user}/agent

RUN curl --create-dirs -sSLo /usr/share/jenkins/slave.jar \
  https://repo.jenkins-ci.org/public/org/jenkins-ci/main/remoting/${JENKINS_REMOTING_VERSION}/remoting-${JENKINS_REMOTING_VERSION}.jar \
  && chmod 755 /usr/share/jenkins \
  && chmod 644 /usr/share/jenkins/slave.jar

# USER ${user}
ENV AGENT_WORKDIR=${AGENT_WORKDIR}
RUN mkdir /home/${user}/.jenkins && mkdir -p ${AGENT_WORKDIR}

VOLUME /home/${user}/.jenkins
VOLUME ${AGENT_WORKDIR}
# WORKDIR /home/${user}

# Docker Image: jenkins/jnlp-slave
#   https://hub.docker.com/r/jenkinsci/jnlp-slave/~/dockerfile/
# uses the script from its git repository:
#   https://github.com/jenkinsci/docker-jnlp-slave

# Docker builder can't copy files under 'config' directory,
# so keep jenkins-slave in top-level dir
COPY jenkins-slave /usr/local/bin/jenkins-slave

ENTRYPOINT ["jenkins-slave"]
```

Comment: Could you post the contents of the whole `Dockerfile` you are using? And also the whole firefox command you are executing? I tried and I could run firefox as root with no problem.

Comment: Thanks @MondKin , I have updated the information as your comments. Could you look over it once again ?

Comment: Why you comments `# USER ${user}`? This not work if you uncomment?

Comment: I just tried your `Dockerfile`, creating an empty `jenkins-slave` file to allow it to build, and then ran this with no problem: `/usr/bin/firefox --screenshot http://www.google.com`.

Comment: @MondKin Thanks man. I don't know if the empty `jenkins-slave` you've mentioned is the `entrypoint`? atm, if i removed the `jenkins-slave` section in my `Dockerfile` and rebuild the image then it's good to run with `root` permission. But if i still keep that `jenkins-slave` section as i did in the above snippet then the problem is still there. Also, i wonder if i set the `USER ...` in the line of Firefox, will it be used with the same USER that i use with `jenkins-slave` section?

Comment: @atline the thing is i can run the other application (Google Chrome) when comment `# USER ${user}` . So i would expect the same thing will be for other ones.